# Creating a dictionary of words and their context in a sentence

Tags: python

I have a Python list containing hundreds of thousands of words. The words appear in the order they are in the text.

I'm looking to create a dictionary of each word associated with a string containing that word with 2 (say) words that appear before and after it.

For example the list: "This" "is" "an" "example" "sentence"

Should become the dictionary:

```
"This" = "This is an"
"is" = "This is an example"
"an" = "This is an example sentence"
"example" = "is an example sentence"
"sentence" = "an example sentence"
```

Something like:

```
WordsInContext = Dict()
ContextSize = 2
wIndex = 0
for w in Words:
    WordsInContext.update(w = ' '.join(Words[wIndex-ContextSize:wIndex+ContextSize]))
    wIndex = wIndex + 1
```

This may contain a few syntax errors, but even if those were corrected, I'm sure it would be a hideously inefficient way of doing this.

Can someone suggest a more optimized method please?

Comment: *You* know *you* are going to overwrite entries with sentences like this one?

Comment: For fast random-access, you keep `list` as your first part (if you have to access that list again, index(10), index(1212) for example. Otherwise, you might consider `collections.deque`. The only problem is that's a linked-list (double, actually). List is `array`, so it is not for random-access. Also, `deqeue` is a double-end queue.... However, `deqeue` might be useful if you have really large `list` (tens of thousands) and you are only walking down one at a time. But I don't think traversing a linked-list is as bad as walking down an array under modern compiler. My 2 cents.

Comment: @eumiro: Yes, I realize I'll be overwriting sentences, and that should be fine. All I need is one 'context' of a word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
words = ["This", "is", "an", "example", "sentence" ]

dict = {}

// insert 2 items at front/back to avoid
// additional conditions in the for loop
words.insert(0, None)
words.insert(0, None)
words.append(None)
words.append(None)

for i in range(len(words)-4):   
    dict[ words[i+2] ] = [w for w in words[i:i+5] if w]
```

Comment: and if you do `[w for w in words[i:i+5] if w]`, the output should be exactly what the OP wanted. +1 for an elegant solution @Dirk!

Comment: @DarenThomas: Where do I use the [w for w in words[i:i+5] if w]?

Comment: Actually, I decided that I don't need to store the context. I just need to write it to a file. Following your code, I was trying something like this: wPos = FIREWordsList.index(w); for cw in FIREWordsList[wPos - ContextSize: wPos + ContextSize + 1]: f2.write(cw + ' '). I have a feeling though that 'index' will do a linear search and be terribly slow. Is there a better way?

Comment: try this:
for i in range(len(words)-4):
    for w in words[i:i+5]:
        if w:
            f2.write(w + ' ')
    f2.write('\n')

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> words = ["This", "is", "an", "example", "sentence" ]
>>> context_size = 2
>>> dict((word,words[max(i-context_size,0):j]) for word,i,j in zip(words,count(0),count(context_size+1)))
{'This': ['This', 'is', 'an'], 'is': ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example'], 'sentence': ['an', 'example', 'sentence'], 'example': ['is', 'an', 'example', 'sentence'], 'an': ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'sentence']}
```

In python `2.7+` or `3.x`

```
{word:words[max(i-context_size,0):j] for word,i,j in zip(words,count(0),count(context_size+1))}
```